# Change color of ::before pseudo-element based on contextual text in CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've got this CSS code snippet which is designed to apply a gradient background to specific text elements. The gradient's configuration is determined by the width of the  tag. Since there isn't an alternative method to directly access the contextual text of any element using pure CSS, this width-based approach is being utilized:

```css
span {
    width: fit-content !important;
    color: #0000;
    background:
        linear-gradient(rgb(247, 117, 110) 0 0) 0/calc(70px - 100%) 100%,
        linear-gradient(hsl(123, 90%, 40%) 0 0) 0/calc(100px - 100%) 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}

span::before {
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: 0.1em;
    background: #d2d7f5;
}
```

```html
<span>Upcoming</span>
<span>Past</span>
<span>Upcoming</span>
<span>Past</span>
```

Is there a way to change the background color of the ::before pseudo-element based on the  element as well?

Comment: Just style pseudo element background. Background is not inherited by elements, so it can't be passed down to pseudo elements

Comment: i wanted the pseudo element color to match the color of the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Although `background` property isn't inheritable, text related properties usually are. Assign text to the `content` property of the pseudo-element `::before` and it will inherit the text color of the `<span>`, see **Figure I**<sup>1</sup>.

#### Figure I

```css
span::before {
  content: "●" /* OR "\0025cf" ¹ */
}
```

### Corrections

**Figure II** is a list of discrepancies that you should be aware of.

#### Figure II

| CSS | Discrepancy | Correction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` width: fit-content !important; ``` | `<span>` is an inline element which already behaves like `width: fit-content`, also the use of `!important` is highly discouraged. | Remove it. |
| ``` background-clip: text ``` | Not needed with `-webkit-background-clip: text;` and `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`<sup>2</sup>. | Remove it. |
| ``` span::before ``` | Focus on the text content, not the shape of the pseudo-element. | Remove everything but `margin` and change `content` to text. |

<sup><sup>1</sup> For additional ascii characters, see this [search](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/circle).</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> For details, see this [article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-clip/#aa-text).</sup>

### Example

```css
/**
 * Any font-size assigned to <html> will be the reference size for 1rem.
 * ex. 2ch = 1rem.
 * ch units is used because 1ch equals the width of a zero: 0
 * font-family: Consolas is a monospace type -- which means all characters
 * are the same size.
 * All of the above styles makes it easier to make more accurate lengths for
 * text widths using rems.
 */
:root {
  font: 2ch/1 Consolas;
}

span {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: 
    /* Red - 1 to 5 characters */
    linear-gradient(#F7756E 0 0) 0 / calc(5rem - 100%) 100%, 
    /* Green - 6 to 11 characters */
    linear-gradient(#45D14B 0 0) 0 / calc(8rem - 100%) 100%, 
    /* Blue - 12 to 19 characters */
    linear-gradient(#27A7E9 0 0) 0 / calc(12rem - 100%) 100%, 
    /* Orange - 20 to 28 characters */
    linear-gradient(#FF8B00 0 0) 0 / calc(17rem - 100%) 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

span::before {
  content: "●";
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<span>012345</span>
<span>0123456</span>
<span>0123456789abc</span>
<span>0123456789abcdef0123</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had neglected to consider this aspect of assigning text to the content property of the pseudo-element ::before

Comment: A color of #0000 is perfectly legal nowadays and supported on the main browsers. See https://caniuse.com/?search=hex

Comment: @AHaworth I was not aware of that, I'll correct that later, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redo your `background`. And in general, the `:before` element easily inherits the `background` properties, write them separately. Here is an example for you:

```css
span {
  color: #0000;
  background: linear-gradient(red, green);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display: inline-flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

span:before {
  content: '';
  width: .5em;
  background-image: inherit;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem<br>Lorem</span>
```

Comment: I possess multiple <span> elements, each accompanied by contextual text. The color of this text is altered based on the width of the corresponding span. I modified the code snippet to enhance its clarity.

Comment: After your update, I understand what you are trying to achieve. But, the `:before` element cannot know whether the `span` will be more than 70px long. So please formulate your questions more precisely in the future so that you don't waste time guessing about your goals.